# NotificationManagerCompat vs NotificationManager

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

What backwards compatibility does

```
NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
```

provide that I don't get from the normal

```
 NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

They both have a `notify` method that worked on my tested devices (down to API level 19).

The Google sample here doesn't even use the `Compat` version once:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-NotificationChannels/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/notificationchannels/NotificationHelper.java

Answer (score 1):

From looking at the source code for `NotificationManagerCompat`, the bulk of the benefits are with regards to canceling notifications and determining if notifications are enabled on API 19 and below.  Specifically with regard to notify(), `NotificationManagerCompat` can leverage side channel notifications on older Android API levels.  This allows you to register a `NotificationCompatSideChannelService` that you can use to provide more robust grouping functionality on these older Android APIs.

Comment: I think side channels is for wearables